# Why object from Git.tagList().call() is not a tag?

Tags: java, jgit

I'm trying Jgit and I want to retrieve all tags of a cloned repository and I want to sort them by Date. That's why I'm trying the following:

```
String path = "path/to/my/git/repo/.git";
Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File(path)).readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();
try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
            List<Ref> taglist = new Git(repository).tagList().call();

            Collections.sort(taglist, new Comparator<Ref>() {
                public int compare(Ref o1, Ref o2) {
                    Date d1 = null;
                    Date d2 = null;
                    try {
                        d1 = walk.parseTag(o1.getObjectId()).getTaggerIdent().getWhen();
                        d2 = walk.parseTag(o2.getObjectId()).getTaggerIdent().getWhen();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    }
                    return d1.compareTo(d2);
                }
            });
        }catch (GitAPIException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that some of Ref returned by `this.taglist = new Git(repository).tagList().call()` are not Tag: in fact an exception is raised by `parseTag()` and its message is:
`org.eclipse.jgit.errors.IncorrectObjectTypeException: Object 3ea2b388b5ef02622312fe08e6935a5f9c655e00 is not a tag.`

Can someone explain me why this happen and how can i solve the problem? 
Thank you all.

Comment: This is entirely up to JGit itself, but in Git, the word *tag* means both *tag name* and *tag object* so it depends on what JGit means by "tag". (Probably only the [tag:jgit] StackOverflow tag is relevant here.)

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm going to remove the git tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, i solved changing the `walk.parseTag(o1.getObjectId()).getTaggerIdent().getWhen();` into `walk.parseCommit(o1.getObjectId()).getAuthorIdent().getWhen();` and same for o2.
Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

JGit's `Git.tagList()` returns a `org.eclipse.jgit.api.ListTagCommand`.

`ListTagCommand.call()` returns type `List<Ref>` [as documented](http://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/ListTagCommand.html).

The [`Ref` interface](http://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Ref.html) is implemented by `ObjectIdRef`, `ObjectIdRef.PeeledNonTag`, `ObjectIdRef.PeeledTag`, `ObjectIdRef.Unpeeled`, and `SymbolicRef`.

You should check the type of the returned value before attempting to do anything with it, or use a try/catch as you have done.

Comment: As I said, the aim is to achieve a sorted list of tags. For some reason, I got it changing the `walk.parseTag(o1.getObjectId()).getTaggerIdent().getWhen();` into `walk.parseCommit(o1.getObjectId()).getAuthorIdent().getWhen();` and same for `o2`. It would be great to understand why this change works.